# Java System.out.print Windows and unicode issue

Tags: java, windows, unicode, cmd

I'm printing out a line that is overwritten (like a status bar) in Windows `cmd.exe`. I'm doing this by using `System.out.print("\r" + fileName + " " + progress)`.

The problem is that if `fileName` is UTF-8, Windows does not correctly return to the beginning of the line and overwrite the last message.

Minor issue, but I'd like to see if there is a solution. Thanks!

Comment: `fileName` is a Unicode string, it doesn't have an encoding. What character is in it and what code page is the console you're printing to? Note that in general Unicode console and filename access is unfixably screwed up in apps/languages like Java that use the MS C runtime's `stdio` implementation.

Comment: You should not expect `\r` to have the meaning of carriage return. Yes, I know that sounds stupid. To make some sort of status bar, you should be using terminal control facilities (no idea how in Java; something like curses in C).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try with `\r\n`:

```
System.out.print("\r" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "bla bla");
```

Comment: i dont follow why i would have to print a new line when i want to overwrite what was last printed.